# toggle background color of multiple buttons individually

Tags: react-native, button, react-hooks, state, render

I'm using map to render multiple buttons at once. I want the background color of one button to change when I press it, but now when I press one button, the color of all buttons change. I can create state for each button to see if it is selected, but if I have a ton of buttons that won't be practical. Is there any workaround for this?

```
 const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(false);
 const genres = ["Adventure", "Arts", "Leisure", "Nature"];
 const onSelect = () => setSelected(!selected);

  buttons = () =>
    genres.map((items) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={items}
        onPress={() => onSelect()}
        style={[
          styles.button,
          { backgroundColor: selected ? "#00cc00" : "#f2f2f2" },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{items}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
```

edit: I would like to have multiple buttons to be selected at one time. If I click on Adventure and Leisure, both their button colors would change but the rest remains unchanged. The colors can be toggled on multiple presses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null);
const genres = ['Adventure', 'Arts', 'Leisure', 'Nature'];

buttons = () =>
    genres.map(item => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={item}
            onPress={() => setSelected(item)}
            style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: item === selected ? '#00cc00' : '#f2f2f2' }]}
        >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{items}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
```

EDIT: Multiply selected

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
const genres = ['Adventure', 'Arts', 'Leisure', 'Nature'];
const handlePress = genre =>
    selected.includes(genre) ? setSelected(selected.filter(s => s !== genre)) : setSelected([...selected, genre]);

buttons = () =>
    genres.map(item => (
        <TouchableOpacity
            key={item}
            onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
            style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: selected.includes(genre) ? '#00cc00' : '#f2f2f2' }]}
        >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{items}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ));
```

Comment: This solution allows only one item to be selected at a time, is this what the author intended?

Comment: @MorKadosh I would like to have multiple buttons selected at one time

Comment: This solution doesn't allow me to toggle between the colors on multiple presses

Comment: Thanks, the edited solution is what i was looking for